# Transpose CSV rows and columns

Tags: python

I am very new to learning Python (using v3) and trying to do two things which I suspect can be done with one program.

The first part is as follows:

Assume csv file 1 has 6 columns by thousands of rows but each group of ten rows needs to be placed into a new rows that will in effect have 60 columns.

E.g. Input1.csv is :

Id, name, text1, text2, text3, text4, unique code
Id, name, text1, text2, text4, text4, unique code

(some of the IDs are duplicates 
And the output1 needs to be:

Unique Id, name, text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, Unique Id2, name, text1, text2, text3... (60 columns) and then it moves to row2...

I am working with this code to start (but open to other ideas):

import csv

with open('Input1.csv','r', encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='ignore') as infile, open('Output1.csv', 'w' , encoding='utf-8-sig') as outfile:

```
fieldnames = ['id', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5']
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for i in range (0,5):
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        for j in range (0,9):
            for column in csv.DictReader(infile):
                writer.writerow(column)
```

I am trying to loop though the 6 columns and then through 10 rows to then output each row as 60 columns...

Traceback shows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/marc/PycharmProjects/first/Convert1.py", line 12, in 
    writer.writerow(column)
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\marc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 151, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))

Part 2 will be adding the new csv to another csv inserting the columns as a group at a particular spot and possibly re-arranging the columns (I am doing part of the column re-arranging above with the fieldnames.

Comment: First of all, load your dataframes using pandas (`import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv('your_filename.csv')`), everything will be a breeze afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to need a bit more assistance as I've not used Pandas...I edited & get stuck. I tried transpose?

import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('input1.csv')
b = a.set_index("ID", drop = False)
b = b.transpose()
print(b)
b.to_csv('outout1.csv'
fieldnames = ['textid', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'ID']
writer = csv.DictWriter(b, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for i in range (0,5):
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        for j in range (0,9):
            for column in csv.DictReader(infile):
               writer.writerow(column)

Comment: If you could give a very concrete example on how your input and output data should actually look like, that would be extremely helpful. For example, how would you name all those 60 columns actually?